# Durandal 2.0, breeze, knockout binding issue

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

Ok.  I have been looking at this for a couple of days and I am stumped. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code. Any help would be great.

I have merged the durandal Starter kit with a modified version of the temphire sample from breeze.

I am trying to load a user from the database when I load the Shell so I can dynamically generate a menu based on the user.  I know the call to the database returns the data.  I can see it in the Data.Results in FireFox.

but when I load the page I get the following error.

"Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: value: firstName
Message: firstName is not defined;
View: views/shell;
ModuleId: viewmodels/shell"

**Shell.js**

```
define(['durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/entitymanagerprovider', 'model/modelBuilder', 'services/errorhandler'],
function (system, router, logger, entitymanagerprovider, modelBuilder, errorhandler) {

    entitymanagerprovider.modelBuilder = modelBuilder.extendMetadata;

    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        attched: attached,
        router: router,
        search: search,
        user: ko.observable()
    };

    errorhandler.includeIn(shell);

    return shell;

    function activate() {
        return entitymanagerprovider
            .prepare()
            .then(bootPrivate)
            .fail(function (e) {
                if (e.status === 401) {
                    return bootPublic();
                } else {
                    shell.handleError(e);
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    function bootPrivate() {

        var self = this;
        log('TempHire Loaded!', null, true);

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from('resource/Users');
        return entitymanagerprovider.manager().executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (data) {
                shell.user(data.results);
                router.map([
                    { route: '', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
                    { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
                ]).buildNavigationModel();
                return router.activate();
            })
            .fail(
                alert("failed")
            );
    }

    function bootPublic() {
        return router
            .makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' })
            .map([
                { route: '', moduleId: 'login', nav: true}])
            .mapUnknownRoutes('login', 'not-found')
            .activate();
    }

    function attached() {

    }

    function search() {
        //It's really easy to show a message box.
        //You can add custom options too. Also, it returns a promise for the user's response.
        app.showMessage('Search not yet implemented...');
    }

    function log(msg, data, showToast) {
        logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
    }
});
```

**shell.html**

```
define(['durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/entitymanagerprovider', 'model/modelBuilder', 'services/errorhandler'],
function (system, router, logger, entitymanagerprovider, modelBuilder, errorhandler) {

    entitymanagerprovider.modelBuilder = modelBuilder.extendMetadata;

    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        attched: attached,
        router: router,
        search: search,
        user: ko.observable()
    };

    errorhandler.includeIn(shell);

    return shell;

    function activate() {
        return entitymanagerprovider
            .prepare()
            .then(bootPrivate)
            .fail(function (e) {
                if (e.status === 401) {
                    return bootPublic();
                } else {
                    shell.handleError(e);
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    function bootPrivate() {

        var self = this;
        log('TempHire Loaded!', null, true);

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from('resource/Users');
        return entitymanagerprovider.manager().executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (data) {
                shell.user(data.results);
                router.map([
                    { route: '', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
                    { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
                ]).buildNavigationModel();
                return router.activate();
            })
            .fail(
                alert("failed")
            );
    }

    function bootPublic() {
        return router
            .makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' })
            .map([
                { route: '', moduleId: 'login', nav: true}])
            .mapUnknownRoutes('login', 'not-found')
            .activate();
    }

    function attached() {

    }

    function search() {
        //It's really easy to show a message box.
        //You can add custom options too. Also, it returns a promise for the user's response.
        app.showMessage('Search not yet implemented...');
    }

    function log(msg, data, showToast) {
        logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
    }
});
```

**entitymanagerprovider.js**

```
define(['durandal/app'],
function(app) {
    breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
    var serviceName = 'breeze';
    var masterManager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

    var EntityManagerProvider = (function() {

        var entityManagerProvider = function() {
            var manager;

            this.manager = function() {
                if (!manager) {
                    manager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy();

                    // Populate with lookup data
                    manager.importEntities(masterManager.exportEntities());

                    // Subscribe to events
                    manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
                        app.trigger('hasChanges');
                    });
                }

                return manager;
            };
        };

        return entityManagerProvider;
    })();

    var self = {
        prepare: prepare,
        create: create,
        manager: manager
    };

    return self;

    function create() {
        return new EntityManagerProvider();
    }

    function prepare() {
        return masterManager.fetchMetadata()
            .then(function() {
                if (self.modelBuilder) {
                    self.modelBuilder(masterManager.metadataStore);
                }

                var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from('resource/lookups');

                return masterManager.executeQuery(query);
            });
    }

    function manager() {

        return masterManager;
    }

}
```

);

Comment: I think you've have a cut and paste error; your `shell.html` is the same as your `shell.js`. The knockout context debugger for Chrome may be able to help you solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see shell.html its pretty difficult to answer this. But you are not exposing firstName to the view. In shell.js, you  would need to make this a variable.

If firstName is a property within user, in your html you would reference this as:

```
<span data-bind='text: user().firstName'></span>
```